# Magento: Adminhtml controllers in frontend?

Tags: php, magento, automation

I'm trying to write a module which allows users create their own shop in our system (multi-store function).

I'm wondering, is it possible to execute an adminhtml controller's functions in Magento frontend?

At this moment, I've just create folder and edit `index.php, .htaccess` when click save website in Magento backend. I need more than that, please help.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a good idea - people who are allowed to create their own store should get an admin account (you know that you can define roles with restricted permissions?)

But to answer the question: it is possible. You will have to create an own frontend controller that simulates a logged in admin user, then forwards to the adminhtml controller action.

### Example (untested):

```
public function saveStoreAction()
{
    $adminUser = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load(ADMIN_USER_ID);
    $adminSession = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
    $adminSession->setUser($adminUser);
    $adminSession->setIsFirstPageAfterLogin(false);

    $this->_forward('save', 'store', 'adminhtml');
}
```

`ADMIN_USER_ID` being the id of a backend user under that you want to perform the action. This shouldn't be your own admin account with full privileges but a dummy account that has only the necessary permissions, or a real account, distinct for each user.

### About _forward():

The method is defined in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` and documented like this:

```
/**
 * Throw control to different action (control and module if was specified).
 *
 * @param string $action
 * @param string|null $controller
 * @param string|null $module
 * @param array|null $params
 */
```

It manipulates the current request object and sets it to "not dispatched", so that the front controller will try again to find a suitable action controller to dispatch it to, this time according to the new parameters.

Actually my first version had a bug, _forward does not take a route like `'adminhtml/store/save'` as parameter but the separate parts in reverse order, `'save', 'store', 'adminhtml'`.

Comment: Thanks for your help fschmengler, could you describe or give me a reference about how `_forward()` work? Well, my work flow will look like this : `user register @ frontend > create role > create user > assign to role > create website,group,store > success`